# Changing Minor and Major values for iBeacon stops me from being able to find the beacon. (iBeacon/Xcode)

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, arkit, ibeacon

I'm trying to connect to 5 iBeacon devices (Minew i10) and I can only discover them when the Major and Minor values are both 0. All UUIDs are the same. I'm printing the beacon information and only get a blank output when Major/Minor values are not 0 and an actual output with range, UUID, minor, major, etc when BOTH Major/Minor values are set to 0.

What might I be doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: UUID(uuidString: "(actual UUID inserted here)")!,
    identifier: "Minew Beacon(s)")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)



        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print(beacons)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a different beacon or a second phone with a beacon transmitter app like Locate Beacon for iOS or BeaconScope for Android.

I suspect you will find that there is nothing wrong with your code, and that you will be able to detect other beacon transmitters with nonzero major and minor values.  I suspect it is the Minew beacon configuration that somehow makes that beacon undetectable when you make your configuration change intended to set major and minor to nonzero values.  Perhaps something is wrong with the way you are configuring it that is applying something different than the intended change.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've had a nother look about and it was because I was using
`llocationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)`
Which was deprecated in iOS 13. 

Instead I have changed it to the following and it is now working.
`locationManager.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: identityConstraint)`

Thanks David.